# Simulating a complex form submission in Python

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I am trying to automated the process of submitting and downloading data from the form on this page:

http://www.mandg.co.uk/investor/funds/american-fund/gb0030926843/historic-prices/

Unfortunately, it is quite complicated, as the "Download Historic Prices" button appears to run some javascript (that modifies the __VIEWSTATE input) in a way that I cannot reproduce.

What is the best way for me to automate the download?

Comment: are you looking for a solution (that would involve some kind of dedicated api from their side) or for a workaround?

Comment: I have emailed them to ask them about it, but I doubt they will provide an API.  So I was hoping that someone with better scripting skills would be able to help me submit the form.